# Closing the second form and opening it again

Tags: java, javafx

I am new with JavaFX and I am trying to learn it by creating a simple inventory system. I would like to ask how to restart a second application?

i.e 
Let's say that form main menu was opened as well as the form employee. By clicking a button from the form employee, form main menu will restart.

Your help is very very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Note: I am not using FXML.

Comment: could you post your current code?